# update the datatable which is dynamically appended after changing the data-order of row jquery

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a table like below which is dynamically appended using jquery:

```
var thead = '<table><thead><tr><th>Unit</th><th>data</th><th>value</th> 
           </thead>';
var tbody = '<tbody>';
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
   tbody = tbody+<td>'+data[i]+'</td>
}
var table = thead+tbody;
$('#divid').append(table);
```

which results in below format

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <th>Unit</th>
      <th>data</th>
      <th>value</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr><td data-order="1"></td></tr>
       <tr><td data-order="1"></td></tr>
       <tr><td data-order="1"></td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I have to do a custom sorting operation on column using the data-attribute.
Initially all my data-attr will have value 1,then on click of first child i will change the value of data-attr =-1 like below:

```
$("body").on("click",".hover td:first-child", function(){
                $(this).attr('data-order',-1);
}
```

now i want datatable to reflect that change meaning the which ever row has data-order=-1 should come first,Should sort in ascending order and the version of jquery-datatable is 1.10.16

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Assuming your jQuery selectors are valid (that is not the case in the question) you could simply call `table.cell(this).invalidate().draw()` in the click handler, see this small fiddle based on your code -> **http://jsfiddle.net/gxsup750/**

Comment: @davidkonrad But my table is dynamically appended table .I have edited the question also.For dynamically appended table its not working

Comment: Basically `data-order` will only work *if* you have `data-order` defined in all rows of the column at initialisation time.  By the edit it seems you build a "simple" table and then try to add `data-order` afterwards? That will not work, `data-order` will be ignored.

Comment: @davidkonrad No No I am generating while i'm building the table like this: tbody=tbody+'<tr><td data-order='+data[i]['sort']+'></td></tr>

Comment: @davidkonrad can you please unmark the question as its not duplicate

Comment: Done. But you will still not be able to change data-order other way than through the API and invalidate.